# AWS RDS Message For gp2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Message : The gp2 burst balance credits for the RDS database instance are low. To resolve this issue, reduce IOPS usage or modify your storage settings to enable higher performance.

I am getting the following message from AWS via email, a bit new to new to RDS any help will be appreciated,  as to how to fix this problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have two choices if you don't want to limit usage of your db:

1. Increase size of your storage, as for `gp2`, the [bigger the size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#Concepts.Storage.GeneralSSD) the more IOPS you get.
2. Change from `gp2` to [Provisioned IOPS SSD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#USER_PIOPS) where you can specify fixed IOPS that you require. Provisioned IOPS SSD will be probably also more expensive.

Comment: Was wondering if increasing the database instance size fix the problem for example from t2.small to t2.medium

Comment: @Delton iops is property of storage. Instance type can Increase overall performance, but will not increase your iops.